# How to find the HTTP status code of a page already loaded in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-codes

I encountered a problem with a website I am responsible for. It displayed a blank page in Google Chrome, due to some failure on the server. I have since fixed the cause of the problem, but I would like to know what HTTP status code it returned when this happened. I still have the blank page open in my browser.

To clarify, I know how to capture the status code for future requests using the Network tab, but I want to access the status code of the page that was just loaded.

Is there some way to use the Developer Tools to *find the HTTP status code of an already open page*, when the Dev Tools were not open while the page was requested?

Comment: Not possible because it's not exposed via [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) retroactively.